# как добавить дату и время к строке

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно с помощью php пересохранить файл с указанием
даты и текущего времени?

Я php-скриптом получаю данные со стороннего сайта. И сохраняю в файл file.html.
Далее данные обрабатываются и публикуются на моем сайте.

Я бы хотела после этоq обработки пересохранять file.html с именем вида: 
03-02-2019 19-00 file.html

Не обязательно именно так, но с указанием даты и времени. Т.к. при следующем обновлении в том же file.html сохраняются уже другие данные, а предыдущие затираются.

Пробовала так:

```
        $date = date("m.d.y"); 
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    $date_time = $date.$time;

file_put_contents('tel{$date_time}.html', $so2);
```

Но получаю файл буквально с таким именем: tel{$date_time}.html
А нужно как-то так: tel03-02-2019_21-31-59.html

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Спасибо!

P.S. Господа минусующие, вы бы хоть объяснили, что Вам не нравится?
Вам, специалистам, может, это и элементарным представляется. А я с php только знакомлюсь. И не могу решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты используешь одинарные кавычки. В них нельзя переменную передавать. Вот если ты укажешь двойные, то все сработает.

Замени `file_put_contents('tel{$date_time}.html', $so2);` на `file_put_contents("tel{$date_time}.html", $so2);`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию copy и при сохранении просто подставьте к названию файла дату и время с помощью функции date(). это первое что пришло в голову на вскидку. P.S (Ну и в целом нужно было бы код в вопросе написать.)